# Is there any way of copying a macro inside a register to a different register?

Tags: command-line, macro, register

I've discovered I can execute vim macros from the command line using the following command:

```
vim myfile -c "argdo norm @aZZ"
```

This command executed from the command line will execute a macro that I have stored inside `register a` and close the file. It works fine, however, I'd like to be able to execute a macro that I have as a string and not a macro that is already inside a register.

Let's say I see my macro using `:reg` on vim, and inside the register `"a` I see `Goa^Ma^Ma^C^C`. If I manually copy `Goa^Ma^Ma^C^C` to a different register with the command `:let @l="Goa^Ma^Ma^C^C"`, this macro will not work on the register `"l` as it works on register `"a`. Is there any way of copying the value of a macro to my clipboard and paste it on another register without breaking it? Just so I can execute macros that I've extracted from my registers on the command line?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Your `let` command should work just fine. However, you need to input `^M` and alike as single characters, with `<c-v><c-m>` for example.

Comment: If the value is stored in the clipboard, you should be able to directly access it using `vim <args> -c ':norm @+' <filenames>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^X` is display representation of byte value of #24 (as "X" is the 24th letter in alphabet). Hence instead of `:let @l="Goa^Ma^Ma^C^C"` you should write:

```
let @l = "Goa\ra\ra\3\3"
```

Escape rules are borrowed from C. Full description is under `:h expr-quote`.

Comment: Complicated to get right—why not ctrl-v insert the characters? Much easier

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't think C-style escapes are too complicated.

Comment: @Matt Thanks... But my issue is more about the situations that I create a very huge macro and I want to execute this macro on a bash script outside vim. The huge problem that I see is that even though I can see the macro that I've created on `:reg`, I still need a lot of rework to adapt this macro to become an executable macro string. Is that how it should be? If I create huge macros and I want to execute them as strings, do I need to dedicate the time for translating what I see on `:reg` to a string using the right characters? Or is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: @raylight See `:h :source!` But a long sequence of normal-mode commands will be hard to read.

Answer (score 4):

If you’re copying from one register to another, do that:

```
:let @l = @a
```

Or if you want to edit,

```
:put a
(Edit)
0"lD
```

The last sequence is to put the macro into register `l` but avoid adding a trailing newline.

Make sure to use literal control characters as necessary (`<C-v>` is useful there).

Comment: @Rich I think `0"lD` works?

Comment: I think I didn't explain it properly in my question, sorry. But in my specific case of use, this method won't work because I want to generate the string of the macro just so I'm able to execute it outside the file. This way, I could use vim macros even inside a process that is automatically receiving files on a server.